# How to track js errors with errbit and airbrake?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, airbrake, errbit

I have a rails application, tracking ruby errors works very well, but how to track js errors?

Comment: interested in this too - have you tried this: https://github.com/airbrake/airbrake-js

Comment: tried without success (

Answer (score 0):

*Disclaimer: I work at airbrake*
You can use https://github.com/airbrake/airbrake-js to track javascript errors.
If you have any issues getting started just email support@airbrake.io